# hrpsys update to make clear command for nextage work

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with the KaWaDa Nextage Open (the real robot, not in simulation). I would like to start a movement by `robot.setTargetPosition(...)` and if some condition is fullfilled while the robot is moving, I would like to stop it again. It seems `robot.clear()`does not have any effect - is this expected behaviour? Using `robot.clearOfGroup(...)`, I get the following error:

```
robot.clearOfGroup('LARM')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-be9ca79979e0> in <module>()
----> 1 robot.clearOfGroup('LARM')

/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hironx_ros_bridge/hironx_client.pyc in clearOfGroup(self, limb)
   1127         if StrictVersion(self.seq_version) < StrictVersion('315.5.0'):
   1128             raise RuntimeError('clearOfGroup is not available with your '
-> 1129                                'software version ' + self.seq_version)
   1130         HrpsysConfigurator.clearOfGroup(self, limb)
   1131         angles = self.getJointAnglesOfGroup(limb)

RuntimeError: clearOfGroup is not available with your software version 315.2.8
```

So I conclude that I have to update hrpsys? How could I do that?
According to apt-get `ros-indigo-hrpsys-ros-bridge is already the newest version.`, the same for ros-indigo-hrpsys.

---

Update: interestingly, there seems to be something wrong with the versions:

```
$ rosversion hrpsys
315.14.0
```

I guess this means there are two hrpsys versions on my system somehow? Does someone have a clue how to trace down the older one?

---

Update 2: I got it now, so on my machine I run hrpsys 315.14.0, while on the QNX there seems to be 315.2.8.
What can solve this issue? Should I downgrade the local hrpsys or can I update the QNX software?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297505/hrpsys-update-to-make-clear-command-for-nextage-work/) by [robotfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28731/robotfan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2018-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Your commands via ipython is to use hrpsys in QNX controller. So it is not related to hrpsys version in ROS system. And as the error message shows, your hrpsys controller on QNX controller, 315.2.8, doesn't support the API `clearOfGroup`.

- https://github.com/fkanehiro/hrpsys-base/pull/704#issuecomment-118189817

I'm afraid you need to update the hrpsys on your QNX controller.

Alternatively, you may be able to stop the motion by overriding with`setJointAnglesOfGroup` API. We don't sure it works, but it may be possible to work with the older version.

Thanks.

Update:

I tried to override setTargetPose by setting JointAnglesOfGroup in simulation, but it didn't work. It jumped to current angle after setTargetPose ends. So I think we cannot go this way.

I think setTargetPose is a bit special function, because it is used only through python interface directly. ROS MoveIt! doen't use this API. It uses joint level API like setJointAnglesOfGroup and playJointAnglesOfGroup and they are overridable (even in old version hrpsys).

---

Originally posted by [longjie0723](https://answers.ros.org/users/31799/longjie0723/) with karma: 56 on 2018-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robotfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28731/robotfan/) on 2018-07-24**:
I believe you are right that updating hrpsys on the QNX would probably be the best solution. How can I do that?

Your suggestion to use `setJointAnglesOfGroup` to override the motion, so you how excactly would you do that? first `setTargetPose`, then `setJointAnglesOfGroup` with the current angles?

**Comment by [longjie0723](https://answers.ros.org/users/31799/longjie0723/) on 2018-07-29**:
Do you need to use setTargetPose for your system? MoveIt! doesn't use this function (because it solve IK by itself).

**Comment by [robotfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28731/robotfan/) on 2018-07-30**:
I would like to do position control, so e.g. pass the robot a 3D coordinate to reach (and then, in some cases stop the movement early). Using setJointAngles is not handy there... is there a function call that would solve the IK for me?

**Comment by [longjie0723](https://answers.ros.org/users/31799/longjie0723/) on 2018-07-30**:
setTargetPose is a option and it works, but overriding is not supported in current version.
Why don't you use MoveIt! and moveit_commander? It can set target pose of hand and overriding is supported.

- http://wiki.ros.org/rtmros_nextage/Tutorials/Programming_Hiro_NEXTAGE_OPEN_MOVE

**Comment by [robotfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28731/robotfan/) on 2019-05-28**:
So I just got back to this issue with a fresh Ubuntu 16 installation and still do not know how to stop a movement. The issue with the hrpsys on the QNX persists but is probably hard to solve.
@longjie0723 If I use moveit_commander, none of the following commands work:

```
larm.go()
#time.sleep(1)
larm.stop()
larm.clear_pose_targets()
larm.clear_pose_target('LARM_JOINT5_Link')
```

...the robot keeps moving.
If I use the MoveIt! GUI, I can also click stop, and the GUI claims it stopped (and so does the terminal output) but the robot does not actually stop. I keeps moving and always fulfils the plan.

Is there seriously no way to get the robot to stop?